# How to authenticate with django-grahql-jwt in a graphene-django Using GraphQLTestCase?

Tags: django, django-graphql-jwt

I use Django and Graphene in my project. I wrote tests with `GraphQLTestCase`. When i try to authenticate users using JWT, i usually get errors.

Here is my code:

```py
from django.test import TestCase

import json

from graphene_django.utils.testing import GraphQLTestCase

from resume.graph.schema import schema

from .models import Post

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

from graphql_jwt.shortcuts import get_token

User = get_user_model()


class PostTestCase(GraphQLTestCase):

    GRAPHQL_SCHEMA = schema

    def test_post_list(self):
        token   = get_token(User.objects.get(pk=1))
        headers = {"HTTP_AUTHORIZATION": f"JWT {token}"}

        response = self.query(
            '''
            query {
                post{
                    user
                    text
                }
            }

            ''',
        op_name = 'post',
        headers=headers,
            )
        content = json.loads(response.content)
        self.assertResponseNoErrors(response)
```

Here are the errors I get after running python manage.py test.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Udemezue\Desktop\resume\post\tests.py", line 25, in test_post_list
token       = get_token(User.objects.get(pk=9))
File "C:\Users\Udemezue\Desktop\resume\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Udemezue\Desktop\resume\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 415, in get
raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
accounts.models.User.DoesNotExist: User matching query does not exist.

Here is the errors i get.

### ======================================================================
FAIL: test_post_list (post.tests.PostTestCase)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Udemezue\Desktop\resume\post\tests.py", line 62, in test_post_list
self.assertResponseNoErrors(response)
File "C:\Users\Udemezue\Desktop\resume\env\lib\site-packages\graphene_django\utils\testing.py", line 75, in assertResponseNoErrors
self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 200)
AssertionError: 400 != 200

---

Ran 1 test in 0.137s

FAILED (failures=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...

Comment: Please, specify: what are errors you mentioned?  What is the ouput of test session?

Comment: You can check them again sir

Comment: Have you setup the test db correctly? Test DB has no Users to begin with-- you have to add the user first in the test setup, then write the test case.

Comment: can you help me with that, give me a sample code of how to create users with the setup method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me.

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from graphql_jwt.shortcuts import get_token
User = get_user_model()
import json


class PostTestCase(GraphQLTestCase):

    def test_post_list(self):
        user = get_user_model().objects.create(username='myuser')
        token   = get_token(user)
        headers = {"HTTP_AUTHORIZATION": f"JWT {token}"}

        response = self.query(
            '''
            query GetUser($username: String!) {
              user(username: $username) {
                id
              }
            }

            ''',
        headers=headers,
            )
        content = json.loads(response.content)
        self.assertResponseNoErrors(response)
```

Comment: I get a 400 when I get implemented this